# Error trying to access jspdf image in Icenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to work with images in JsPdf in Icenium and it is showing me the following error in the Console and i am stuck .

```
 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL     data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJ…    NpemUgOAovUm9vdCA3IDAgUgovSW5mbyA2IDAgUgo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNjk5CiUlRU9GCg== from frame with URL     http://app.icenium.com/Mist/Workspace/pdf/Simulator?targetUrl=http%3A%2F%2F…    Style=Default&allowedOrientation=Portrait%3BLandscape&fullResolution=false. The frame     requesting access has a protocol of 'http', the frame being accessed has a protocol of ''.     Protocols must match.
```

The following is my js file:

```
 function demo1() {

        var imgData ='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/.....';
        //You'll need to make your image into a Data URL
// Use http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker
        var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.setFontSize(40);
    doc.text(35, 25, "Octonyan loves jsPDF");
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
        doc.output('datauri');



    }
```

Could you please tell me how to go about this or any other way in which i could get an image in pdf in icenium.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access it through an iframe based emulator it won't work.

Try it on the device. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use their browser based client and simulator which would not work in CORS scenarios.

Fortunately Icenium has Windows based client and simulator that you can use for such purposes or test on device as Rahat suggested.